# Random variable of random variable

Tags: gaussian

This is confusing and difficut, but I hope it makes a sence.
I am interested in kind of like Random variable of Random variable.
This issue might've been mentioned below before.

[The Probability distribution of Random variable of Random variable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107364/the-probability-distribution-of-random-variable-of-random-variable)

Let me clarify.
Random variable of Random variable (RVoRV) here is **not**
add/subtract operation of two random variables.
It is about a single  measurement of random variables, where each variable actually came from another random variable.
or I should say, list of values for a  distribution , where each value comes from its own parent-distribution. but measurement was done only once

Is there any material or anything that mentioned this issue?

As an example,
I made matlab code below.
It creates N different gaussian distributions with their N standard deviations chosen uniform randomly with some variance.
Then it draw a single value from each of N different gaussians as random variable, making a list of N values.
now what is the standard deviation of this N value list?
As i run this code over and over, sd stays near a certain value.
Any equation for that?
Thank you.
--------------------------

clear all;
close all;
clc;

N=100000;% number of gaussian distributions

% mean for N gaussians -------------
%gauss_list_mean=**rand**(1,N).*20+10;%average
gauss_list_mean=repmat(0,1,N);%average same value

% sigma for N gaussians -------------
gauss_list_sd=**rand**(1,N).*20;%standard deviation
%gauss_list_sd=repmat(15,1,N);%standard deviation same value

%-----------------------------------------------------------------
% draw a value from each of N different gaussian distributions
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
if 0% fast version
 list_drawn_value=**randn**(1,N).*gauss_list_sd+gauss_list_mean;
else% slow
     list_drawn_value=zeros(1,N);
     for i=1:N
        list_drawn_value(i) = normrnd(gauss_list_mean(i),gauss_list_sd(i));
 end
end

sd_value=std(list_drawn_value);%Get standard deviation of values from N different gaussians

fprintf(' sd of drawn values from %d Gaussians =%g \n',N,sd_value);

fprintf('mean(gauss_list_sd)=%g  std(gauss_list_sd)=%g\n',mean(gauss_list_sd),std(gauss_list_sd));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question will surely be closed, because it's not on topic for this site.

Nevertheless ... notice that the (pseudo-)random samples created by your code, say $X_1,...,X_N$, are such that each $X_i = \mu_i + \sigma_i Z_i$, where $\mu_i = 10 + 20\,U_i$ and $\sigma_i = 20\,U_i'$, with $Z_i\sim \text{Gaussian}(0,1)$, and $U_i,U_i'\sim \text{Uniform(0,1)}$, and all are mutually independent.

Thus, the $X_i$ are i.i.d. with $X_i = 10 + 20\,U_i + 20\,U_i'\,Z_i$, and their sample variance is therefore a consistent estimator of $V(X_i)= 20^2V(U_i) + 20^2\,V(U_i'\,Z_i)$.

Now $V(U_i)=\frac{1}{12}$ and $V(U_i'\,Z_i)=E({U_i'}^2\,Z_i^2)-[E(U_i'\,Z_i)]^2 = E({U_i'}^2)\,E(Z_i^2)=\frac{1}{3}\cdot1$, so you should be seeing a sample standard deviation near $20\sqrt{\frac{5}{12}}$ (if I haven't made any arithmetic errors).

Comment: Sorry for off topic and thank you for the answer. It is a great help, now i feel i know how to solve all other problems like this one as well. Greatly appreciated.